# How to install multiple OS in one PC?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I use Ubuntu 14.04.I want to install multiple OS(including windows 10,fedora and other linux distribution).
I need windows only for use Oracle database.I tried to install Oracle database
in Ubuntu,but couldn't.

My hard disk is 500GB.
I want to create 80GB(Ubuntu),50GB(fedora),20GB(windows),35GB(another OS),35GB(another OS),4*50GB(another OS so that i will able to install any OS in any time in this pertition).
How can I do it?
My current status-[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the notice: Define a root system as instructed. That is mandatory for any Linux system. It means you need to create a partition named "/".  (in the image you are missing a mount point named "/").

If Oracle is the only thing you need I would install Ubuntu as the only operating system, install virtual box in  Ubuntu, install Windows in virtual box and then Oracle in Windows.

Saves you rebooting from and into one of the operating systems.

Comment: Thanks.I install Oracle virtual box but couldn't install Windows.I don't know how to install OS in VM.

Comment: You  put the windows dvd in the machine, start virtualbox and point to the dvd. Not that hard ;-)